# How to connect mySQL data base (on hosting which does not support Node.js) to React application (JS)?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, hosting

Need your support and assistance. **Problem:** host provider does not support Node.JS (only buying another hosting plan which I don`t want to do). **I am using:** React App (Javascript), also packages 'mysql' and 'express' and unfortunately low knowledge of PHP language (time question).
I am familiar how to connect using Node.JS (at very basic level).

**Question (I guess simple question)**: Is it possible to connect mySQL data base located on hosting which does not support Node.js by using Java Script (React App)? And how to use retrieved data from mySQL?

Thank you so much.

Comment: does your hosting provider support PHP? [See this then](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/connect-mysql-with-php/)

Comment: Do you intend to rewrite your nodejs backed program in php? Most cheap hosting providers offer that. Do you intend to run your nodejs program on one host and your MySql server on your current hosting provider? Ask your provider how to access your MySql server from outside their internal network.

Comment: Yes, this host supports PHP for sure but does exist a way to use in all  React project let say PHP config file (like a bridge between App and data base)? Just imagined that

Comment: Writing all of your backend written on nodejs to PHP would be a tedious task. If you have only started and does not have a backend(full-fledged one) yet, you can try migrating to php. If you have already built an app, migrating to a new hosting provider who supports node js woul be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment no big projects started yet. I `ve got some useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674187/how-do-i-connect-javascript-and-mysql-via-php

Comment: hope that will work out

Answer (score 0):

Directly you cannot connect react as a front end language to a mysql database on your server without a go between server side language such as php. With a php endpoint you can use mysqli to connect to the mysql database on the server you are connecting to.

you will need to use this form:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    //accepts cors access from all locations
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    
    //login to your mysql db
    
    $hn = 'localhost';
    //The below change
    $db = 'dbname';
    $pw = 'yourpassword';
    $un = 'root';
    
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die("Can't Connect");
    
    //the rest are called prepared statements
    $query = 'select id from accounts where name=?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $input);
    
    $input = "someValue";// $_GET['input'];
    
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($idOut);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    return $idOut;
elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS'){
// this allows react to not explode on cors preflight        
}
```